# How to draw line with different markers by pgfplots or tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line

I would like to draw a line that is similar to the one shown. 
[image]

Now I do something like this.

[image]

Can someone help me ? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
    \begin{axis}[
    width=9.5cm,
    height=5.5cm,
    ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    %nodes near coords,
    legend style={at={(0.15,0.96)},anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    ]
    \addplot [mark=*,mark size=2pt,mark options={fill=blue!80!white},]
        coordinates {(0,0.2) (0,0.6)};
    \addplot+ [mark=triangle*,mark size=2pt,mark options={fill=blue!80!black},]
        coordinates {(0.5,0.4) (0.5,0.8)};
    \legend{A,B}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to work with symbolic scatter classes.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
    \begin{axis}[
    width=9.5cm,
    height=5.5cm,
    ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend style={at={(0.35,0.96)},anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=*},
        b={mark=o,draw=black}
    },
    ]
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=*}
    \addlegendentry{Before repacking}
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=o}
    \addlegendentry{After repacking}
    \addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit symbolic] coordinates {(0,0.2)[a] (0,0.6)[b]};
    \addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit symbolic] coordinates {(0.5,0.4)[a] (0.5,0.8)[b]};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set the fillcolor explicitly in square brackets.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95]
    \begin{axis}[
    width=9.5cm,
    height=5.5cm,
    ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend style={at={(0.35,0.96)},anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    colormap={fake}{
rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,0)}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=*}
    \addlegendentry{Before repacking}
    \addlegendimage{only marks,mark=o}
    \addlegendentry{After repacking}
    \addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit] coordinates {(0,0.2)[1] (0,0.6)[0]};
    \addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit] coordinates {(0.5,0.4)[1] (0.5,0.8)[0]};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]